# What is the easiest and the fastest way to center a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone suggest me the fastest way to center a div in CSS ? Thank you !

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to center vertically or horizontally ?

Comment: Both. Can you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Example 1: Center div using `margin-auto`

https://i8pn0.csb.app/margin-auto-example.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dashed 1px black;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  /* Center horizontally*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### Example 2: Center a Div Horizontally using `display: flex`

https://i8pn0.csb.app/flex-x.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Center child horizontally*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

### Example 3: Center a Div Vertically using `display: flex`

https://i8pn0.csb.app/flex-y.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dashed 1px black;
  /* Center vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

> These examples are not the only way but the easiest, and some of them only work on modern browsers.